# Jquery that avoid autocomplete

Tags: jquery, browser, autocomplete

in one of stacks questions i found a way to avoid autocomplete with jquery, without change all forms and all fields. Why? Cause i have a huge system and was looking for a way to do it in a 'smart way'.

However i don't have any iOS gadgets to try this one. Autocomplete 'off' on inputs was not working. My question is: it's compatible with IE(argh), Firefox, Opera, Safari?

Question nº 2: is there a way to test in multiple browsers without installing all of them?

```
$('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
$('form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Comment: Looks like you may have troubles with IE 6, 7 or 8. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Any way to avoid this? Today i don't allow users to access the system trough IE [and maybe all developers should do that ?!].